# Information on how to programmatically build directions

Tags: maps, directions

*I realize this isn't a question with an exact answer so it may not be ideal for SO, but I don't know of any other place online to ask this type of question. Please let me know if there's a better place/way to ask this.*

---

I'm investigating how to build an app for generating directions on my campus.  Basically allowing someone to get directions to any location on campus from wherever they are.  I'm interested in finding out if there is any research/libraries/best practices for this sort of thing.  So far Googling has only found results for how to show routes in Google Maps.

**What I've figured out so far:**

My idea is to create a network of nodes.  Each node will have a number of text strings that are the instructions on how to get to every neighboring node, from whichever direction the user is coming.

An A* algorithm can be used to find the path for the user, and the instructions from the relevant nodes can then be displayed.  However, a T-intersection for example, would require 6 different instructions.  Even in a small campus, the number of instructions is ... lots.

I feel there's a more efficient way to do this, but rather than wrack my brain for hours and re-invent the wheel, I thought I'd ask if anyone had resources to existing wheels.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to figure out how to provide an app to a local college that gives turn by turn directions to different buildings.

Comment: @Jarrette Nope.  Other projects came up so this kind of got dropped.  I did keep at it for a while, but it was fruitless.